# WinJS two way binding

Tags: winjs

I have a dynamically filled list witch I bind to a list view. Now I like the input fields editable. I've tried two way binding, but does not work.

This is my template and list definition:

```
<div id="templateList" data-win-control="WinJS.Binding.Template">
            <div id="templateGrid">
                <div data-win-bind="innerText: project"></div>
                <div data-win-bind="innerText: subProject"></div>
                <div data-win-bind="innerText: activity"></div>
                <div> <input id="txtTaetigkeit" type="text" data-win-bind="value: taetigkeit" /></div>
                <div> <input id="txtAuftraggeber" type="text" data-win-bind="value: sAuftraggeber" /></div>
                <div> <input id="txtTotal" type="number" data-win-bind="value: total" /></div>
                <div> <input id="txtTotalV" type="number" data-win-bind="value: totalV" /></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- define content -->
        <div id="contentWrapper">
            <div id="templateOverview">
                <div id="contentGridTemplates">
                    <div id="userTemplates" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ListView"
                        data-win-options="{itemDataSource : actTemplates.itemList.dataSource,
                                itemTemplate: select('#templateList'),
                                layout: {type: WinJS.UI.ListLayout},
                                tapBehavior: 'directSelect'}">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Thanks Marlowe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WinJS doesn't provide for two-way data-binding at present. This means you need to implement your own change handlers for the controls that reflect the data changes back to the data source. You can find an example of this in the [Declarative Binding sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/DeclarativeBinding-bfcb42a5) in the Windows 8 SDK.

Comment: @Marlowe Shameless self-promotion, a library I wrote called [Eight.js](http://eight.codeplex.com) provides a handler for doing Two-Way bindings with common controls so you don't have to write it yourself.